# Why does Windows 2012 search work like this?

Tags: windows-server-2012, search

Here is a search for "XA":

http://picpaste.com/b934e893ca7d05d1c3e7dca9b0324f9f.png

Search results are fine - note the first hit. Now search on "XA01" and nothing is returned:

http://picpaste.com/864abea48ff1fa9b857917d404bca252.png

Search on "ukmac-xa01" and it re-appears:

http://picpaste.com/d99d55d3ab27b592e80838f37abe2d34.png

So why does searching on "XA01" return nothing?

Comment: I don't know, but I find a similar thing in the Windows 7 and 8 start menu search. e.g., I have `putty.exe` the SSH client, and in the start screen search, the following queries have no results: `{p, pu, put, putt,, putty., putty.e, putty.ex}`. Only these two exact queries will find it: `{putty, putty.exe}`. What's the sense behind this not-very-good-search behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong , but from my experience it searches for the first letters from the separate words . if you would search for uk and ukmac then your results should be as expected . As far as I know (from experience ) it doesn not search for in-word "letters" .That can be changed from search options (Windows Explorer).

You could use Agent Ransack (freeware utility ) or powershell cmdlets for more advanced search options .